# Remove text box of MS word document

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-office

I have few MS word documents which contains text in text boxes. I want to remove those text boxes but keep the data as it. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get hold of the text from inside the textboxes using something like `ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text` and then you could delete it by doing something like `ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).Delete`, and after that you'd have to put the text you retrieved from the text box in the relevant part of the document.

Comment: It seems that this will delete only the first text box ? and i have too many. in short on each page text is in a text box.

Comment: @Umar Siddique: Yes, you'd have to put it in some kind of loop, something like `foreach(Shape s in ActiveDocument.Shapes)' might work.